Proposition for Using Denotions in Infinity
Would it help much in mathematics if infinity was denoted by u for uncountable and c for countable? We could also use number sets, like ♾️_i could just be the infinite set of integers, with ♾️_2i being the normal set of even numbers, and even though they’re both infinity, we’d know that ♾️_2i = 2♾️_i and also use like other equations. Not sure if anyone’s tried this before but I feel that it could be useful in some capacity.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The standard notation for countable infinity is $\aleph_0$. There is not a single uncountable infinity so a notation for it wouldn't make sense.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

There are also already notations like $2\mathbb Z$ for the even integers, etc.
